# Why do I have no sound anymore?

Tags: 10.04, sound

I hope this question is appropriate for this forum. I have an embarrassing problem. After trying to get Ekiga-Softfon running I suddenly have no sound anymore at all. But I can't tell how I caused this problem anymore.

Below I have collected some relevant information:

```
lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS

uname -r
2.6.32-25-generic

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [ICH6           ]: ICH4 - Intel ICH6
                      Intel ICH6 with STAC9752,53 at irq 16

aplay -l
**** Liste der Hardware-Geräte (PLAYBACK) ****
Karte 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], Gerät 0: Intel ICH [Intel ICH6]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0
Karte 0: ICH6 [Intel ICH6], Gerät 4: Intel ICH - IEC958 [Intel ICH6 - IEC958]
  Sub-Geräte: 1/1
  Sub-Gerät #0: subdevice #0

aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav
Wiedergabe: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Noise.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono

lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio 
00:1e.2 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) AC'97 Audio Controller [8086:266e] (rev 03)
    Kernel driver in use: Intel ICH
    Kernel modules: snd-intel8x0

ps -C esd
  PID TTY          TIME CMD

ps -C arts
  PID TTY          TIME CMD

ps -C pulseaudio
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1239 ?        00:00:00 pulseaudio

grep "^audio" /etc/group | grep "$USER" | wc -l
1

lsmod | grep "snd"
snd_intel8x0           25588  1 
snd_ac97_codec        100646  1 snd_intel8x0
ac97_bus                1002  1 snd_ac97_codec
snd_pcm_oss            35308  0 
snd_mixer_oss          13746  1 snd_pcm_oss
snd_pcm                70694  3 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss
snd_seq_dummy           1338  0 
snd_seq_oss            26726  0 
snd_seq_midi            4557  0 
snd_rawmidi            19056  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event      6003  2 snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                47263  6 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              19098  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device          5700  5 snd_seq_dummy,snd_seq_oss,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
snd                    54148  12 snd_intel8x0,snd_ac97_codec,snd_pcm_oss,snd_mixer_oss,snd_pcm,snd_seq_oss,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
soundcore               6620  1 snd
snd_page_alloc          7076  2 snd_intel8x0,snd_pcm

head -n 3 /proc/asound/card0/codec#0
head: „/proc/asound/card0/codec#0“ kann nicht zum Lesen geöffnet werden: No such file or directory

head -n 3 /proc/asound/card0/codec97#0/ac97#0-0
0-0/0: SigmaTel STAC9752,53

PCI Subsys Vendor: 0x1028

head -n 3 /proc/asound/card0/codec97#0/ac97#0-0+regs
0:00 = 6a90
0:02 = 0000
0:04 = 0000

asoundconf list
asoundconf: Befehl nicht gefunden

cat ~/.asoundrc
pcm.pulse { type pulse }
ctl.pulse { type pulse }

cat ~/.asoundrc.asoundconf
cat: /home/rasmus/.asoundrc.asoundconf: No such file or directory
```

There are some bits of German: "Befehl nicht gefunden" means "command not found", "kann nicht zum Lesen geöffnet werden" means "cannot be opened for reading".

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Also asked at http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ploetzlich-kein-sound-mehr-21/.

Comment: ubuntu.stackexchange.com beats forum.ubuntuusers.de? see http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/ubuntu-bei-stackexchange/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I agree with koanhead. Double check your hardware, try rebooting of course and check alsamixer. You can just type in "alsamixer" in the terminal and check all the settings. There's also a graphical front end available from the software center. You should be able to find it by searching for "alsamixer" in the software center.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. If had messed up the hardware settings. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anything in those listings that would cause such a problem so far as I can see.

However, just to be complete, let me ask: Did you check your mixer settings? Nothing is muted?

Do you have a Live CD handy with which to test the audio? My audio recently flaked out and I spent a bunch of time troubleshooting before I discovered it was a hardware problem (chipset fan died causing overheating; adding a fan fixed all symptoms).

The thing I find most suspicious is that the aplay command apparently worked without error, yet you didn't hear the sound.